# No unique bean of type [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] is defined

Tags: junit

I am trying to make two testcases using class `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`. Both testcases are in different classes so I made two different beans for them.

On running the junit tests I got a error like that

> Error creating bean with name 'testcases.TestAdminMethodsWebService':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'admin': : No
>   unique bean of type
>   [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 7: [admin, rules]; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type
>   [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2: [admin, rules]

My bean is like this:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller_admin" contextPath="a.com.b" />
<bean id="admin" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller_admin" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller_admin" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://dev05:8080/.." />
</bean>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller_rules" contextPath="r.com.b" />
<bean id="rules" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller_rules" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller_rules" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://dev05:8080/.." />
</bean>
```

please tell me how to overcome with this problem or why this error occurs any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this is the right answer

```
  public class TestClass {  

protected WebServiceOperations admin;
admin = (WebServiceOperations) getApplicationContext().getBean("admin");
protected WebServiceOperations rules;
rules = (WebServiceOperations) getApplicationContext().getBean("rules");

// ... Rest of the class
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Qualifier` annotation to help Spring determine which bean should be injected.

```
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("admin")
    WebServiceTemplate admin;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rules")
    WebServiceTemplate rules;

    // ... Rest of your class

}
```

Read up on the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) under the section Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers.

**Update:**

You also need to change your xml bean definitions like this:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller_admin" contextPath="a.com.b" />
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <qualifier value="admin"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller_admin" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller_admin" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://dev05:8080/.." />
</bean>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller_rules" contextPath="r.com.b" />
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <qualifier value="rules"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller_rules" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller_rules" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://dev05:8080/.." />
</bean>
```

Note the inclusion of `<qualifier>` tag under each bean definition.

Comment: @Qualifier("admin")
public class TestClass {}

Comment: You have to post more information from your xml context file, if you are using xml configuration. If you using the `@Service` or `@Component` annotations instead, you have to give the bean a name like `@Service("BeanName")` and make sure the name matches what you pass into `@Qualifier`.

Comment: I have edited my question now please tell me what should be done

Comment: same problem still exists. I know this is the right solution for this kind of problem, but still if you can give any other method to overcome this problem then please tell me..

Comment: Hey suggest me .. I am a java developer and now i am having a opportunity to become a andriod developer . What should be done ?? should I leave the java field or not??

Comment: Alright let me try if it is right I'll accept it .. Thank you for your response

Comment: So I should move towards android because nowadays its value is increasing